# Finding point on logarithmic curve, given $3$ points and $y$-axis constraint.

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, interpolation

Let's say I have a curve where the $y$-axis goes from $0$ to $1$, and the $x$-axis goes onto infinity.

I have three points: $[0,0]$, $[250 \, 000, 0.5]$, $[1 \, 000 \, 000, 0.9]$.

How could I interpolate these points to give me some multiplier to determine a $y$-value at a given $x$-point?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the form that you're trying to fit? Is it $ y = a \log x + b$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I've tried to conceptualize this a number of ways, but I last tried to do `y = ax^2 + bx + c` and find what a & b were given those three points -- but did not get results like I was expecting.

Comment: @Moo thank you for this, I have one question though: Is there any way to solve this with unknowns? Assuming we always have one point being $[0,0]$, and some unknowns like $p0 = [x_0, y_0]$ and $p1 = [x_1, y_1]$ can we do something like: $a = \frac{(p1_y - (\frac{p0_y * p1_x}{p0_x}))}{(p1_x^2 - p0_x * p1_x)}$

And then have $b=\frac{p0_y}{p0_x} - p0_x * a$

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Moo I did see the lagrange interpolation before, and plotted the points on a graph, and noticed that as the curve got to `1,000,000` it actually sloped down. I actually want it to continue increasing -- or approach `0.9` until infinity (but really get close to it at 1,000,000. Would I need to do some sort of logarithmic equation for this?

Comment: @Moo it's been a hot minute since I've done any sort of math -- I'm actually trying to create a program in Python right now utilizing this to calculate a point on an "exponential" or "logarithmic" curve -- have any resources to guide me on that exponential?

Comment: @Moo this sure sounds like it! I'm not familiar with Numpy -- nor logarithmic functions to be honest -- but I'm going to read up on this. Thank you so much for your time and patience!